# Copy entire column from listview to another listview with same column format

Tags: c#, listview

I am trying to have 2 listviews that in the end will act as mirrors of each other. In the first listview I am able to populate it from a DB with no issues. I have another list view that when a row is checked in the first listview(listVariants) the user can move the entire row to the second listview (addFCList). With the code below it is working, sort of. The issue I am having is when another item is checked from listVariants, the way it is added to addFCList is inline and it just wraps. each item and subitem is being added to the listview as an individual item.

I have both listview cloumns setup the same. My question is how to I get the second listview(addFCList) to be the same as the the first listview(listVariants)? Am I missing something obvious...

*EDIT* I have solved this but will leave it here to help someone out in the future.

```
for (int i = 0; i < listVariants.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (listVariants.Items[i].Checked)
            {
                string UNI = listVariants.Items[i].SubItems[9].Text;

                    bool nameInsert = true;

                    for (int t = 0; t < addFCList.Items.Count; t++)
                    {
                        if (addFCList.Items[t].SubItems[9].Text == UNI)
                        {
                            nameInsert = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (nameInsert)
                    {
                        addFCList.Items.Add((ListViewItem)listVariants.Items[i].Clone());
                    }                                           
            }                
        }
```

Thanks for any help and suggestions.

Comment: Your code adds a ListViewItem.  It doesn't add sub-items to it.

Comment: It only adds text from one column or subitem of the item. I need all subitems to be added.

Comment: So write the code, use a for() loop.  It is very unclear why you have trouble writing that code.

Comment: I guess I am wondering if I can just grab the full row or if I need to get each subitem.

Answer (score 0):

```
listView1.Columns.AddRange((from ColumnHeader item in listView2.Columns
   select (ColumnHeader)item.Clone()).ToArray());
```